# Permanently unprotect a workbook containing VBA macros in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

When I remove protection from the workbook, worksheets and VBA modules of an  Excel 2010 .xlsm file and then save it, when I open it again all protections are back up again. How to remove all protections permanently?

Comment: Have you tried to save as another file, and then opening that one to test? The file itself may be set to have protections enabled.

Comment: And have you checked to make sure a macro does not enable protection automatically?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad  Thank you for your comment. Yes, I did check the macros and commented out all code that was setting the protection on/off, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @QuickishFM  Thank you for your comment. What do you mean by "as another file"? If using a different file name, then yes, I did try that. Is there some other level above workbook where the protection can be set?

Comment: @Confounded instead of saving to the file, choose Save As and save as another file of the same format.